# redirect to custom page

Tags: 7, hooks, redirection

In my custom module, I created a custom link using

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
$items['addcontent'] = array(
    'title'
    => 'Confirmation page',
    'page callback'
    => 'add_content_confirmation',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
);
return $items;
}
function add_content_confirmation() {
return 'Thank you';
}
```

When I check **mydrupal/addcontent**, this link works fine

In my **template.php**, I added

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'my_form_id'){
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_submit';
}
function my_custom_submit()
{
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'addcontent';
}
```

wich redirects me to my home page.

if I write

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/mycontent';
```

That works fine.

How can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
function my_custom_submit()
```

Should be this:

```
function my_custom_submit($form, &$form_state)
```

Right now you are setting redirect on a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you, I did and cleared my cache but usually redirects me to my home